# $\exists C>0$ such that $\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x}) \le e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2-Cx}$?

Tags: exponential-function, taylor-expansion

It is well-known and easy to check that for any real $x$ it holds
$$
\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x}) \le e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}.
$$
[To show this, it is sufficient to write explicitly their Taylor series expansion]

**Question:** does there exists a positive constant $C$ for which for all reals $x$ it holds
$$
\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x}) \le e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2-Cx}\,\,?
$$

In other words, can we improve the upper bound on the hyperbolic cosine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left hand side is $1+o(x)$ the right and side is $1-C.x+o(x)$ so the difference is $-C.x+o(x)$ and is $<0$ if $x$ is small $>0$

Comment: Have you tried looking, as suggested, at the linearization at zero? Or even putting the $-Cx$ term on the left and comparing those Taylor series since you will be then asking $\frac{1}{2}(e^{(C+1)x}+e^{(C-1)x})$??$e^{x^2/2}$

Answer (score 0):

Well, I made the calculations, and 
$$
e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}-\frac{1}{2}\left(e^x+e^{-x}\right)=\frac{x^4}{4}+O(x^6),
$$
so..